# Why so useful functions are not in official build?

Tags: versions, experimental-features

Why so useful functions are not in official build:

Bevel node in cycles:

[image]

Apply properties disabling in Apply scale:

[image]

These functions have been implemented for a long time. Relay, are these functions so dangerous that they can not be included in the build? Or are they not included for another reason?

Comment: For one reason or another they are not considered stable or complete enough for general public use, so to avoid endless bug reports and potential work loss they are removed from view from less advanced

Comment: Not enough people, not enough time, personal preferences...

Comment: Also, (not in this case) many features are too specific and it is a better decision to leave them out so only people who want those features will have to deal with the *bloat* of space and speed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about software development practices, not Blender.

Comment: @JakeD ok, close all questions with tag 'development'

Comment: @Crantisz From `development` tag description: *"does not include general programming questions"*; this question is about software best practices and why the Blender Foundation chooses to develop the way they do, not a *"coding question about addon or script development, and the Python API"*. At best this is an opinion-based question that does not belong on BSE. I don't think that you will get any more of an answer than the first 3 comments from Duarte, brockmann, and I.